# FROM vs. IN in the context of SHOW

Tags: mysql, sql

E.g., `SHOW TABLES FROM...` or `SHOW TABLES IN....`

Is there a preference?  Is one faster than the other.  In the context of `SHOW`, are each weighted equally?

Thanks.

Comment: And I'd also ask: do they do the same thing?

Comment: That was the biggie.  I have a feeling also that the silence so far speaks volumes, as if people are using it interchangeably (but everyone probably has a preference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same thing. About performance, they are most probably equal too. Unless we count the microseconds that the parser needs to check a word.